# Restrict PI to LAN only on specific interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, systemd-networkd, networkmanager

I found out that manual network interface configuration should be done in */etc/dhcpcd.conf*, not in (*/etc/network/interfaces*). Using the example right from the config file I added the following to the */etc/dhcpcd.conf* file:

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
```

**The goal is to restrict *eth1* interface to LAN only**, so it does not connect to the internet. For that I intentionally omitted the *static routers* line, which I assumed was equivalent to the *gateway* specification in the */etc/network/interfaces* file. However, PI still can connect to the internet - so maybe the "unspecified gateway" was defaulted and automatically added by the system?

I saw some suggestions to use the firewall, but I was hoping that there was a way to configure this specific interface through the network configuration file. I still want other interfaces like **eth0 to be able to connect to the internet**, so blocking WAN access through ufw may not be the best solution. Any suggestions on how to restrict eth1 interface to LAN only?

Comment: In case someone else has the same question - using keyword `nogateway` will do the trick.

Comment: You can add the fix as an answer and mark it so :-)  Helps others see that there is a fix and stops the unanswered question coming back time and time again.  Odd but perfectly acceptable practice here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's seems to be a simple solution - use **nogateway** keyword - reference [dhcpcd.conf man(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html):

- **nogateway** Don't install any default routes.
- **gateway** Install a default route if available (default).